# UIView not resizing to fit content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, resize

I have `UIView` (annotationView), that has 2 UILabels, some separator and 1 image.
I want to resize the view, so it has minimal size that will fit the elements inside.
It has constraints to stick to the edges of the view and keep distances between elements.
[image]
[image]

When using the `annotationView`, I simply created `UIView` and set it's class to annotationView in IB (yellow on the picture below). It has no constraints, but it always show with the size I create it in Interface Builder.

[image]

What should I recheck and set to fit the content with minimal size of view?

My implementation of annotationView:

```
//used when loading from storyboard
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    DLog(@"Initializing ICProgressPlotAnnotationView - from XIB");
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)commonInit {
    //load the interface file from .xib
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ICProgressPlotAnnotationView" owner:self options:nil];

    _view.frame = self.frame;
    [_view setNeedsDisplay]; //view is linked to the main view in .xib see image below

    DLog(@"ICProgressPlotAnnotationView VIEW frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    DLog(@"ICProgressPlotAnnotationView frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    //add as a subview
    [self addSubview:self.view];

    [_title_DOWNLabel sizeToFit];
    [_title_UPLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

[image]

EDIT1:

Additional info on constraints:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Now every time I want to change label, I also call `sizeToFit` on both labels and `_view` property in `annotationView`.

They change sizes properly after that, but `_view` does not.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 3:
Also sharing my viewHierarchy:

```
 <ICProgressPlotView: 0x7fff1404d960; frame = (56 60; 263 567); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ed4070>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fff11ee8b60; frame = (0 0; 263 567); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11edc9e0>>
   |    |    |    | <ICProgressPlotAnnotationView: 0x7fff11f3e2a0; frame = (0 0; 276 67); autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ce49e0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fff14054120; frame = (0 0; 276 67); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff14054290>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fff140513e0; frame = (8 32.5; 260 2); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11cb81c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fff140538a0; frame = (31 8; 27 17); text = '35.1'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fff14053ab0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fff14054300; frame = (8 9; 15 15); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff14054730>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fff14051740; frame = (8 42.5; 68.5 13.5); text = 'TITLE DOWN'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fff14051d30>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fff11ee8cd0; frame = (8 525; 3.5 13); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11e0ea50>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fff11ee8e40; frame = (0 0; 3.5 13); text = ' '; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fff11e934d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fff11eece70; frame = (27.5 546; 3.5 13); text = ' '; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fff11e69e00>>
   |    |    |    | <CPTGraphHostingView: 0x7fff11e1f840; frame = (19.5 0; 243.5 538); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fff11edc9b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ed1d40>>
   |    |    |    |    | <<CPTXYGraph: 0x7fff11d132d0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {243.5, 538}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    | <<CPTPlotAreaFrame: 0x7fff11f3c750> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <ICProgressPlotView: 0x7fff1404d960; frame = (56 60; 263 567); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ed4070>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<CPTGridLineGroup: 0x7fff11ef4380> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<CPTGridLineGroup: 0x7fff11ef3b30> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<CPTXYAxisSet: 0x7fff11eef990> bounds: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<<CPTXYAxis: 0x7fff11ef0670> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> with range: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x7fff11ef9630> {-0.5, 6}> viewCoordinates: {0, 0} to {204, 0}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<<CPTXYAxis: 0x7fff11ef2840> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> with range: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x7fff11ef96f0> {-10, 120}> viewCoordinates: {20.4, 0} to {20.4, 498}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <<CPTPlotGroup: 0x7fff11e30b80> bounds: {{0, 0}, {204, 498}}> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <ICProgressPlotView: 0x7fff1404d960; frame = (56 60; 263 567); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ed4070>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <ICProgressPlotView: 0x7fff1404d960; frame = (56 60; 263 567); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ed4070>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fff11efb100; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11ef9a60>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fff14100000; frame = (0 667; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fff11efbc10>>
```

EDIT 4:
autolayoutTrace gives results:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

•UIWindow:0x7fe600f30900
|   •UIView:0x7fe600ed3490
|   |   *ICProgressPlotView:0x7fe600fbfb90
|   |   |   +UIView:0x7fe60300d890
|   |   |   |   *ICProgressPlotAnnotationView:0x7fe6030083c0
|   |   |   |   |   +UIView:0x7fe60300ac00
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7fe600ed66b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fe60300a240'32.3'
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7fe60300ade0
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fe600ed6ac0'4.5'
|   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7fe600fc4760
|   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fe600fc48d0' '
|   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fe600fc5490' '
|   |   |   |   *CPTGraphHostingView:0x7fe600fc2280
|   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe600edcb50
|   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe600edd590

Legend:
    * - is laid out with auto layout
    + - is laid out manually, but is represented in the layout engine because translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
    • - layout engine host
```

Comment: what kind of constraints did u give ?

Comment: Added info about constraints: generally all elements have to keep distances to view boudaries (and they keep, but they are resizing and not the view itself). No intrinsic sizes specified.

Comment: What is the height of time down in the end result? If it has no contents then calling sizetofit might make the height 0.

Comment: DownTitle has content - "Title Down". I've investigated it a bit and: the size of labels during commonInit are changing after sizetoFit to smaller sizes (from big values given in xib), but after that they change back to bigger ones (maybe some other autolayout calculations are ongoing?). I will check the values and will write them down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. Not absolutely sure why it happened, but when making the yellow View smaller than desired size (e.g. always smaller than planned content inside) it resized to be bigger properly.
Changing the contentHugging and Content Compression resistance priorities did the job.